Caching multiple APIs with RxJS in Angular
I have a component with multiple tabs, where users can go back and forth. I need to load the data from the backend in the first tab. This creates unnecessary HTTP calls each time component 1 is re-initialized. My idea is to make the caching service in which I would store the result of the HTTP Call and when the component is re-initialized, it will get data from the service (not from the backend).
Here are some other requirements:

Service needs to be provided in the parent component (when the component is destroyed, service and cached result should also be destroyed)
First HTTP call should be triggered on Component 1 initialization, not on Service initialization

It somehow starts working until I add Subject for triggering the first load. Now, it is triggering an HTTP call every time component 1 is re-initialized.
Stackblitz demo
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

I would try to simplify the solution by reducing the amount of unnecessary Subjects/Observables. Using shareReplay() operator helps with not calling the backend each time: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ytbrcx?file=src%2Fmain.ts

The reason your code is fetching every time you load Component A, is because you call triggerLoad$.next() each time Component A initializes!
You don't actually need a separate trigger, you can simply declare a single codetables$ observable that both fetches and caches the data.
  readonly codetables$ = from(this.codetableTypes).pipe(
    mergeMap(codetableType => this.getCodetable(codetableType)),
    scan((acc, current) => ({...acc, ...current}), {} as CodetableOptions),
    shareReplay(1),
    takeUntilDestroyed()
  );

Here we use shareReplay to cache the value. It behaves like a ReplaySubject(1); when consumers subscribe, they will receive the latest value immediately.
Here's a working Stackblitz

That's the same as what I wrote in the comment :)

You should have wrote it up as an answer :-D

The most simple "cache" system I've seen is store the data in variables
data!:any[]
getData()
{
   if (this.data)
      return of(data)

   return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
      tap((res:any[])=>this.data=res))
}


Yes, this is one of the options that comes to my mind. The whole codebase is using a declarative way though. Maybe there is some more reactive solution.
